# android action bar spacing between icons

Tags: android, android-actionbar

Below is action bar in my app, there is a separator between search icon and cart icon, when i put a separator as an item in menu.xml file, there is more gap between search and cart icons.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ImSF.png)
is there any way to put separator between icons without taking much gap.

Any android code required, please help me out.

Actually, I used separator as an item and made padding '0 dp' on both sides of each item. But separator also takes the space, how much other items took, that's why there is more space, Can anyone tell other way, that separator takes less space than remaining items ?
Thanks

```
<menu
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:appcompat="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
    android:name="android:actionButtonStyle"
    android:id="@+id/menu_search"
    android:title="@string/action_search"
    appcompat:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"
    appcompat:showAsAction="always"
    />
    <item
    android:name="android:actionButtonStyle"
    android:id="@+id/separator"
    android:icon="@drawable/search_divider_bar"
    android:title="separator"
    appcompat:showAsAction="always"
    />
    <item
    android:name="android:actionButtonStyle"
    android:id="@+id/cart"
    android:title="@string/action_cart"
    app:actionLayout="@layout/actionbar_cart"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    />
</menu>
```

Comment: I checked those solutions, but not worked for me

Comment: Actually, I used separator as an item and made padding '0 dp' on both sides of each item. But separator also takes the space, how much other items took, that's why there is more space, Can anyone tell other way, that separator takes less space than remaining items ?